# Using nodejs passport-google-oauth2 without a redirect URI

Tags: node.js, passport.js, google-oauth, passport-google-oauth2

I'm using the nodejs npm module [passport-google-oauth2](https://github.com/mstade/passport-google-oauth2)

I'm currently using it exactly the way its example shows, with a redirect URI that the google oauth will callback with, after successful authentication:

Example:

Server side:

```
var GoogleStrategy = require( 'passport-google-oauth2' ).Strategy;

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID:     GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://yourdormain:3000/auth/google/callback",
    passReqToCallback   : true
  },
  function(request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return done(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```

Client side:

```
app.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: 
    [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read' ] }
));

app.get( '/auth/google/callback', 
    passport.authenticate( 'google', { 
        successRedirect: '/auth/google/success',
        failureRedirect: '/auth/google/failure'
}));
```

I know there is a way to use Google OAuth *without* redirect; it simply somehow stays on the same page (Google SSO). I think you can do it with just a `GoogleVerifier`, rather than building a `new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest()` (Java examples), but I'm rather lost at this point.

Questions:

1. How to use google oauth2 without redirect URI ? (I know it can be done  using GoogleVerifier object in Java).
2. Am I using the wrong module for Google SSO in NodeJS ?  Is the module above appropriate for Google SSO using OAuth2 ?  It is for Google OAuth2, but is it SSO-able ?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: make sure y understand the difference between Authentication and Authorization. Also be more specific in what you mean by "use".